# API Gatewayにオーソライザーを設定できない。

Tags: aws, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

API Gatewayでメッセージを返すだけのAPIを作成しました。

Lambdaのブループリント(API Gateway custom user authorizer)を使ってオーソライザー用のLamda関数を作成して動作することを確認しました。

[API Gateway コンソールを使用した Lambda オーソライザーの設定](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/apigateway/latest/developerguide/configure-api-gateway-lambda-authorization-with-console.html)の手順に従ってAPIにオーソライザを設定すると下記のエラーがでます。

```
Invalid token source expression: method.request.header.. The source must be a method request header, matching 'method.request.header.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+'
```

Answer (score 0):

`オーソライザー`の設定画面で`トークンのソース`にLambdaにトークンを渡すパラメータ名を設定していなかったことが原因でした。

オーソライザーを適用するパスを設定するのだと勘違いして`/foo/*`のような設定も同様なエラーになります。

初歩的な間違いでした。。